# Why is Adding Renjin to POM.XML causing WAR file not to deploy (logging library issue)?

Tags: renjin

When I add this dependency to my SpringBoot application:'

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.renjin</groupId>
    <artifactId>renjin-script-engine</artifactId>
    <version>3.5-beta76</version>
</dependency>
```

My WAR file will not deploy and throws "Error starting child" exceptions in the Tomcat log.

Specifically, here is the main log entry in catalina.out;

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory loaded from file:/Users/.../Library/tomcat-9.0.41/webapps/.../WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.36.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory
```

How can I figure out how to remove the "offending file" (slf4j-jdk14-1.7.36.jar), since it's not explicitly loaded in pom.xml and seems to only have a conflict to due adding the org.renjin dependency?

Since I don't explicitly have any logging in the pom.xml, I'm unsure how to fix this problem.

Not loading the dependency above "fixes" it, but I'm not sure why the dependency breaks the deploy or how to fix.

Suggestions appreciated.

Thanks,